# Is there a limit on how many divisors a natural number can have in it size (amount of digits)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, asymptotics

I would like to know if there was a growth limit on the number of divisors a number has.

It seems the [divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) measures the magnitude and not the size of a number. Again, I am looking for a limit in the size of the number, not the magnitude.

So is there any growth limit for a number's divisors given the size of the number?

Edit:  I am only considering positive whole number divisors.

Comment: What distinction are you making between size and magnitude? An example would be useful.

Comment: @RobArthan Consider highly composite numbers. A number can have 10 digits but has 1000s of divisors.  The amount of divisors doesn't exceed the magnitude of the 10 digit number, but it does exceed the number of digits (eg. 10)

Comment: So by "size" you mean the number of decimal digits?

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, I do mean the number of decimal digits.

Comment: It's easy to go convert the magnitude to (what you are calling) the size, using the function $x \mapsto \log_{10}(x)$ and to convert back again using the function  $x \mapsto 10^x$. So I don't see what your problem is.

Comment: @RobArthan "So I don't see what your problem is." A lack of knowledge & education.

Comment: I didn't mean to sound pejorative. Apologies, if I did. What I meant was "doesn't that solve your problem?". (And plaudits for your touching reply!)

Comment: @RobArthan  He seems to be asking about this: With equality at $n = 6983776800 = 2^5 \cdot 3^3 \cdot 5^2 \cdot 7 \cdot 11 \cdot 13 \cdot 17 \cdot 19$ and $d(n) = 2304,$
$$ d(n) \leq n^{ \left( \frac{\log 2}{\log \log n} \right) \left( 1.5379398606751... \right)} =  n^{ \left( \frac{1.0660186782977...}{\log \log n} \right) }. $$